# error : [error] Source '__libgdx_setup_tmp\prj-common\src\MyGame.gwt.xml' does not exist

Tags: java, xml, gwt, libgdx

Im getting this error when creating the project with `libgdx`

```
[error] Source '__libgdx_setup_tmp\prj-common\src\MyGame.gwt.xml' does not exist
```

and then it cleans and done

What do i do to resolve this?

Links:
settings - http://prntscr.com/2tuv5f

error - http://prntscr.com/2tuv6u

Answer (score 1):

The error states that "MyGame.gwt.xml' does not exist". The "gwt" part of that means that that relates to the GWT project (html based). But since you did not select to generate this project this error is not really a concern. If you were generating an html project then it may be a problem. This error may be a bug I am not sure. Just import the projects into eclipse and they should work

Comment: Thats the point, the files never generate. After the error it cleans and then it says its done. The files are nowhere to be found.

Comment: but it does not matter since you are not using a gwt project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's something related to the libgdx library latest version 0.9.9. A bug or similar. Try downloading the previous version(0.9.8). Fortunately, it worked for me.